# Chinese resources don't work with .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, localization, .net-3.5

We have a strange bug with our localised resources in Chinese, when using .Net 3.5. This problem affects console apps AND Windows Forms apps, and it's easy to reproduce.

Basically, the Chinese resources aren't being used, but other resources (for example, French and English) ARE being used. Furthermore, it works fine if we use .Net 4.x.

It goes wrong on Windows 7 and Windows 10 (I haven't tried Windows 8.x, but I expect that would go wrong too).

It's easy to reproduce with a Console application:

1. Create a default .Net 3.5 Console application.
2. Add a default resource file, "Resources.resx" and add to it a name/value pair: **Test, I'm English**
3. Add a "Resources.fr.resx" file and add to it a name/value pair: **Test, I'm French**
4. Add a "Resources.zh.resx" file and add to it a name/value pair: **Test, I'm Chinese**
5. Add the code below to the `Main()` method

Code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
Console.WriteLine(ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Resources.Test);
```

(The first line is merely a convenience so that we can test this code on a non-Chinese system. We can remove that line when running on an actual Chinese system because the CurrentUICulture locale is going to be already Chinese without having to modify it - and the bug still occurs.)

In Control Panel | Region, change Format to *English (United States)* and run the program. The output will be:

```
en-US
I'm English
```

Now change the region format to *French (France)* and run the program. The output will be:

```
fr-FR
I'm French
```

Now change the region format to *Chinese (Simplified, China)* and run the program. The output will be:

```
zh-CN
I'm English
```

Note that it's not working.

Now change the project properties to build a .Net 4 or later version, without changing anything else, and re-run it. Now the output is:

```
zh-CN
I'm Chinese
```

So it works with .Net 4!

My questions are:

- Can anyone else reproduce this?
- Is this a known bug?
- Is there a workaround?

Comment: Bit of a landmine, zh-CN and zh-CHS and zh-Hans all mean simplified Chinese.   If you want a match on zh-CN then you have to pick the simplified Chinese that's specific to mainland China.  Titled "Chinese (Simplified, PRC)" in the designer.  If you want fallback then you have to use zh-Hans for your resource.  Something like that.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll try that. This seems to be some kind of bug that they fixed in .Net 4.x, because it should fall back to "Resources.zh.resx" for all subcultures of Chinese (and indeed does in .Net 4.x). I have discovered that using "Resources.zh-CN.resx" works in .Net 3.5, but  then the other dialects won't, I'd assume.

Comment: I found this blog, which seems related: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2007/12/13/zh-hans-zh-hant-and-the-old-zh-chs-zh-cht/. Also the [documentation for CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) explicitly mentions this too, so it looks like that will be the answer: Use `zh-Hans` as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hans' comment (which was the correct answer) I have the complete answer now.

It seems that in .Net 3.5, "zh" is NOT recognised as a neutral Chinese culture.

In .Net 4.x, "zh" IS recognised as a neutral Chinese culture.

We can see the difference by comparing [the .Net 3.5 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.isneutralculture%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for `CultureInfo.IsNeutralCulture` with the [.Net 4.0 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.isneutralculture%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The .Net 3.5 documentation lists the following neutral and specific resource names:

```
zh-CHS Chinese (Simplified)                    : neutral
zh-TW  Chinese (Taiwan)                        : specific
zh-CN  Chinese (People's Republic of China)    : specific
zh-HK  Chinese (Hong Kong S.A.R.)              : specific
zh-SG  Chinese (Singapore)                     : specific
zh-MO  Chinese (Macao S.A.R.)                  : specific
zh-CHT Chinese (Traditional)                   : neutral
```

The .Net 4.0 documentation changes to:

```
zh-Hans Chinese (Simplified)                    : neutral
zh-TW   Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)           : specific
zh-CN   Chinese (Simplified, PRC)               : specific
zh-HK   Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong S.A.R.) : specific
zh-SG   Chinese (Simplified, Singapore)         : specific
zh-MO   Chinese (Traditional, Macao S.A.R.)     : specific
zh      Chinese                                 : neutral
zh-Hant Chinese (Traditional)                   : neutral
zh-CHS  Chinese (Simplified) Legacy             : neutral
zh-CHT  Chinese (Traditional) Legacy            : neutral
```

We can see that .Net 4.0 has gained "zh" as a neutral Chinese culture.

So this is not a bug in .Net 3.5, but a documented feature.

If you need to be compatible with both .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.x it seems that you need to use "zh-CHS" (for Simplified Chinese), although it is not clear whether this will continue to work indefinitely.